# Use LINQ variables out of context

Tags: c#, linq

How can i use "x" variable in if block?  I want to return Id field of x if statement is true.

```
if (UserList.Any(x => x.Type == (int)UserType.SuperUser))
{
    return x.Id;
}
```

Comment: some more information would be nice....

Answer (score 5):

You can't access the "LINQ variable" outside the lambda expression.

What you want to do is to get the `Id` property of any element `x` that satsify the condition `x.Type == (int)UserType.SuperUser`.

In this case, replace your `Any()` by [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx).

```
var item = UserList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == (int)UserType.SuperUser);
if(item != null)
    return item.Id;
```

`FirstOrDefault(x => condition on x)` return the first element that satsify the condition and `null` if no element satisfy the condition.

If you want to get the `Id` value of all elements that satisfy the condition, use the [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) and [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) extention methods:

```
return UserList.Where(x => x.Type == (int)UserType.SuperUser).Select(x => x.Id);
```

`Where(x => condition(x))` returns an `IEnumerable` that contain all elements that satisfy the condition if you prefere to get a "normal" list, add `ToList()` before `;`.

Answer (score 1):

How many matches are you expecting : i.e. how many users in your list do you expect to have the SuperUser type?

If you expect there to be exactly one user that matches (so having zero matching users or more than one matching user would be an error), then use Single:

```
return UserList.Single(x => x.Type == (int)UserType.SuperUser).Id;
```

(Note this will throw an exception if there isn't exactly one matching user; alternatively you can use SingleOrDefault and then test for null.)

If you expect there to be one or more and you just want to return the first one:

```
return UserList.First(x => x.Type == (int)UserType.SuperUser).Id;
```

(Note this will throw an exception if there isn't exactly one matching user; alternatively you can use FirstOrDefault and then test for null.)

If you expect there to be one or more and you want to return an array of all the Ids of all the matching users:

```
return UserList.Where(x => x.Type == (int)UserType.SuperUser).Select(u => u.Id).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the nice answers already posted.

To make the last code sample from Sam Holloways answer look like you are using the x directly you could rewrite that to the SQL-like syntax (don't remember what that is called):

```
IEnumerable<int> userIds = from x in UserList 
                                    where x.Type == UserType.SuperUser 
                                    select x.Id;
```

You can use the count method on userIds to determine if there's anyone satisfying your condition.

Since you are returning the id, and I guess the id is an int and you'll have to return something anyway, and that I guess you would return 0 if it's not there you could use:

```
return UserList.Where(x => x.Type == UserType.SuperUser).Select(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```